# How to use NGNIX directives to redirect all requests to files in a directory except for requests to files in a specific subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress site where we want to control access to files in the media library. This means all files inside the `/uploads/` directory need to be inaccessibile to non-logged-in users with the exception of a single subdirectory of files, `/uploads/public/`. I have a file called auth.php in the root of my site that does the actual permission checking. Currently there is not an exception for files inside the `/public/` directory. Also, auth.php appears not to be called with this directive added to the `server {}` block in my site.conf.hbs file in my local ngnix environment. Here are the contents of my site.conf.hbs file. My directive is at the bottom:

```
upstream php {
  {{#each fastcgi_servers}}
  server {{this}};
  {{/each}}
}

server {
    listen {{port}};
    root   "{{root}}";

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #
    # Generic restrictions for things like PHP files in uploads
    #
    include includes/restrictions.conf;

    #
    # Gzip rules
    #
    include includes/gzip.conf;

    #
    # WordPress Rules
    #
    {{#unless site.multiSite}}
    include includes/wordpress-single.conf;
    {{else}}
    include includes/wordpress-multi.conf;
    {{/unless}}

    #
    # Forward 404's to WordPress
    #
    error_page 404 = @wperror;
    location @wperror {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    #
    # Static file rules
    #
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        add_header        Cache-Control "no-cache, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           5m;
        add_header        Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|otf) {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;

        expires           5m;
        add_header        Cache-Control "public";

        # allow CORS requests
        add_header        Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    #
    # PHP-FPM
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED         $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $host;

        fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $fastcgi_https;

        fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_buffer_size      64k;
        fastcgi_buffers          32 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout     1200s;

        proxy_buffer_size        64k;
        proxy_buffers            32 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size  256k;
    }

    # Protect all uploads:
    if (-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ /auth.php?file=$1 break;
    }
}
```

If it helps, here is the first chunk of code in my auth.php file that I'm using right now to ensure we're even hitting auth.php:

```
<?php

    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require_once('wp-load.php');

    wp_die('We made it to auth.php');
```

Comment: Add two `location` blocks and place this code inside one of them. Also, you will need to change `break` to `last` otherwise the PHP file will just be downloaded.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, Thanks for the suggestions but I have a few questions. 1) I think downloading the PHP file is desired so that I receive a login prompt on that image url if the image is not inside ````/uploads/public/````. I have similar functionality working on another site that uses .htaccess - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zogf7gh9kenjls/4l4um5fb.png?raw=1

2) Are you able to give me a code example using location that accomplishes this? Unfortunately I have basically no knowledge of nginx directives.

3) Don't I need a rule specifically to exclude ````/public/````?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does you existing configuration look like? The contents of the `server` block would be good, so that we can see what other `location` blocks are present. Please edit the question to add it, then we can make more detailed suggestions.

Comment: I've added the contents of a local test site's config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx will choose the more specific prefix `location`, so to catch `/wp-content/uploads/` but exclude `/wp-content/uploads/public/`, you could use two prefix locations.

For example:

```
location ^~ /wp-content/uploads/ {
    if (-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ /auth.php?file=$1 last;
    }
}
location ^~ /wp-content/uploads/public/ {
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           5m;
    add_header        Cache-Control "public";
}
```

The `^~` is necessary to avoid the other `location` blocks (*static file rules*) taking precedence (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details). It also prevents the ability to upload PHP files to your server and execute them.

The `if` block prevents `/auth.php` receiving requests for files that do not exist. The `rewrite...last` is necessary to pass control to `location ~ \.php$`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

The second `location` block contains appropriate cache control rules for the public folder.

Comment: Thank you for this, but unfortunately nothing is happening on my test site after adding this to the bottom of my `server{}` block in my site.conf.hbs file. Do you have any ideas on what I should try or details I should add? As a side note, if this ends up working I promise to set a bounty on this question tomorrow and award you the points.

Comment: Check `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to ensure that Nginx is seeing the correct configuration. Check the access log and error log to ensure that the request is reaching the server. Comment out `log_not_found` statements so you actually see the errors. Test using `curl` to avoid browser based side-effects.

Comment: It turned out I needed to stop and restart my site in order for these rules to kick in (I'm using software called "Local" for local wordpress dev). I will return tomorrow to set a bounty and mark your answer as correct. Thank you so much for you help.